# Multiple Websites with different Domains and https on same Ip

Tags: html, docker, nginx, web

Hello i have one Linux Server with one Ip-Adress. What i want to do is i want to host 4 or more different Websites/Services on this Server, all these should have https

I know that it is possible to set some websites on different Ports, but i want this.

I read stuff about docker & ngix reverse proxy. Could someone link give me a good explanation.

Thanks
Maty

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to host 4 different domains on the same server, then

first install NGINX with these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
```

Then,

1. create 4 different `domain.conf` files in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory. ( here **domain** can be anything that you can remember to map the sites ).
2. paste the below code with some modifications:

   `server{`
       `listen 80 default_server;`
       `listen [::]:80 default_server;`
       `server_name **domain**;`
       `location / {`
         `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;`
         `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`
         `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`
         `proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;`
         `proxy_redirect off;`

   `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:**port**/;`
         `proxy_redirect off;`
      `}`
   `}`

In the above code, change the **domain** and **port** accordingly.

3. run `sudo nginx -t` and check if there's any issue raised.
4. restart the nginx server ( `sudo service nginx restart` )

Now it should be running on 4 different servers with **HTTP**

**For HTTPS**

1. Install **certbot**

- `apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install certbot`
- `apt-get install python-certbot-nginx` ( try `apt-get install python-certbot-nginx` for Ubuntu 18.04 and later )

2. Run the following command to generate certificates with the nginx:

- `sudo certbot --nginx -d domain.com -d www.domain.com`

Now if you look at the `domain.conf` files of `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` , you notice the certbot added few lines.

Now restart the nginx server and boom!!!! it works.

**Note** : you have to purchase those domains with the domain providers.

Hope this helps you!!!
Infact I stucked very much to keep this docs with me previously...
comment if you get any errors or doubts.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer...

yes i own these domains, more like 2 domains ans some subdomains of then, but that shoud not be important, or? I have these four:

domain1.com
  - sub1.domain1.com
  - sub2.domain2.com
domain2.com

I understood completly how to use ngix and certbot, but where i put the actual Website Data? I would guess that i host them with for ex. apache on 4 different ports and put these ffour different ports in the four domain.conf files right? 

or do i get anything wrong?